# unable to execute insert query using table called 'order'?

Tags: mysql

Database name : test
table names   : order, order_shipping,order_payment

The query below gives me error

```
INSERT INTO order(order_status,customer_id) values('booked',1)
```

> error : 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(order_status,customer_id) values('booked',1)' at line 1

But the exact same query will work if i add database name before tablename

```
INSERT INTO test.order(order_status,customer_id) values('booked',1)
```

> result : insertion successfull

I renamed tablename 'order' to 'order_main' and it works without database name

```
INSERT INTO order_main(order_status,customer_id) values('booked',1)
```

> insertion successfull

My question is why does not my original query work without database name attached to table name. Is it because I have other tables starting with this table name ???

table in my database : order, order_shipping,order_payment

Comment: `Order` is reserved word in mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order` is a [reserved keyword within MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). If you want to use it as an identifier, enclose it in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (order_status,customer_id) values('booked',1)
```

In the second query, you specify a full identifier, which MySQL does not mistake for a keyword. Hence, it works without problems.

Comment: Thanks Sirko.. Did not think like that....  Thanks also for taking the time to explain it to me... :)